# MODX Revo album list pagination

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I want to make pagination for my albums list using Gallery. 
Trying to do it with getPage. 
For photos inside album all works perfect:

```
[[!getPage?
        &element=`Gallery`
        &limit=`8`
        &album=`portfolio`
        &totalVar=`gallery.total`
        &thumbWidth=`180`
        &thumbHeight=`150`
        &containerTpl=`NewGalleryAlbumTpl`
        &thumbTpl=`NewGalItemThumb`
        &cache=`0`
        &cache_expires=`0`
        &pageNavVar=`page.nav`
    ]]
<div class="system-nav-orange">
<span class="pages">Page [[+page]] from [[+pageCount]]</span>
<ul class="pager">
[[!+page.nav]]
</ul></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

but for albums pagination shows, but doesn't work:

```
    [[!getPage?
        &element=`galleryalbums` 
        &rowTpl=`rowTpl`  
        &pageNavVar=`page.nav` 
        &limit=`1`]]
<div class="system-nav-orange">
<span class="pages">Page [[+page]] from [[+pageCount]]</span>
<ul class="pager">
[[!+page.nav]]
</ul></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gallery does not support getPage out the box. You can [edit the source code](https://forums.modx.com/thread/37769/revolution-gallery---how-to-add-pagination) but not very future proof. There is also a possible work around which doesn't require code changes: https://forums.modx.com/thread/37769/revolution-gallery---how-to-add-pagination?page=2#dis-post-439685

However I would recommend looking at MoreGallery. It's a premium extra so not free but does [support pagination](https://www.modmore.com/moregallery/documentation/getpage/) and is far superior to Gallery imo.

Comment: David, thanks for your piece of advice. But I can't really belive that I can't do standart pagination of albaum list in most popular gallery module.

Comment: Nice idea by the way - https://forums.modx.com/thread/74574/pagination-for-gallery-albums

Comment: Yep it's a pain but don't think gallery is supported very much these days. The MODX core team have forked it so you could add issue here: https://github.com/modxcms/Gallery

Comment: I've added extra link to my answer which may work without code changes.